# Не получается подключить библиотеку GStreamer

Tags: c++, library, gstreamer

Следовал совету по подключению с этой страницы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294685/how-do-i-configure-visual-studio-2017-to-run-gstreamer-tutorials.
После чего файл туториала:

```
    #include <gst/gst.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#endif

int
tutorial_main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline =
      gst_parse_launch
      ("playbin uri=https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm",
      NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg =
      gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
      GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* See next tutorial for proper error message handling/parsing */
  if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg) == GST_MESSAGE_ERROR) {
    g_error ("An error occurred! Re-run with the GST_DEBUG=*:WARN environment "
        "variable set for more details.");
  }

  /* Free resources */
  gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(__APPLE__) && TARGET_OS_MAC && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  return gst_macos_main (tutorial_main, argc, argv, NULL);
#else
  return tutorial_main (argc, argv);
#endif
}
```

Начал выдавать ошибки по типу: `GstElement` не определён. И куча ошибок такого рода, в зависимых файлах библиотеки происходит тоже самое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вон их целых 5 тысяч! Я читал, что динамические и статические библиотеки могут конфликтовать здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58251955/unable-to-include-gstreamer-in-c-program. Но я уже сам не понимаю, что может, а что не может. Причём с командной строкой всё работает, и примеры запускаются,а как дело доходит до подключения библиотек, то происходит такое. Буду рад и благодарен, если мне объяснят и помогут в решении проблемы.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: *GstElement не определён* - ¿В каком месте он определен? ¿Каким образом это определение становится доступно в месте использования?

Comment: @user7860670 Это класс библиотеки, который должен быть определён с подключением заголовка этой самой библиотеки, но проблема как раз в том, что большинство методов не видна и он просто не определяет структуры и переменные. Возможно проблема  с зависимостями библиотеки.